# Confused coding a discord bot

Tags: bots, discord

When I have done everything correctly and have scripted correctly the comes up when i put node . in command prompt I even have a valid token!! ::

`(node:8744) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.       at Client.login (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub TigerDuo\TigerDuo\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:204:52) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub TigerDuo\TigerDuo\index.js:47:5) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 (node:8744) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag` --unhandled-rejections=strict`(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1) (node:8744) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

and this is my script let alone i have setup heroku and github:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'MyNeverToBeSharedToken';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Online.')
    bot.user.setActivity('the Tiger Duo server!', {
        type: "WATCHING"
    })
    bot.login(process.env.token);
```

Comment: You need to renew your token and to never share it again, that's like sharing your password

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing dotenv package

```
require("dotenv").config()
```

And add this to the top of your code

Comment: True, note it's supposed to be set in the environment for exactly the reason above, so it doesn't get shared by accident (e.g. git, StackOverflow questions, etc.)